# Basic summation issue

Tags: summation

I am having some trouble prooving the following summation formula. As `a and b` are constants I got the constant part out of the sum and tried to split the summation (such that sum of `a to b` is the same as sum of `1 to b` minus sum of `1 to a` plus `a` for example), but it always ends up with an expression that never simplifies to this result. I also spent a lot of time looking for the formula for this summation and somehow cannot manage to find exactly this:

$$\sum_{i=a}^b i \cdot \frac{1}{b-a+1} = \frac{a+b}{2}$$

How do we get from left to right here? Or even simpler, what is the formula for just this sum?

$$\sum_{i=a}^b i$$

Comment: Hint: The sum is an arithmetic series with common difference 1. How many terms does the series have?

Comment: It has (b-a+1) right?

Comment: yup! So what does the summation have to equal?

Comment: Use Gauss's trick : If we write down the sum twice , once from $a$ to $b$ , then from $b$ to $a$ we get $b-a+1$ pairs summing up to $a+b$. Hence the value of the sum is $\frac{(a+b)(b-a+1)}{2}$

Comment: ((b-a+1)(1 + (b-a+1))) / 2. I see the idea. But at the end I am at (b-a+2)/2 :( I'm gonna cry soon.

Comment: Peter gave you the answer :)

Comment: @Peter ok I put that on paper and finally I got it, thank you so much. I was probably over-complicating it trying `sum(1 to b) minus sum(1 to a) plus 1` using the `n(n+1)/2` formula. I don't get why that did not work though.

Comment: @AnneBauval it does exactly, so this question is kind of a duplicate, sorry. But there is no way I know how to even begin to look for this, can you look for MathJax?

Comment: For your approach,$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^bi - \sum_{i=1}^ai + a &= \frac{b(b+1)}{2} - \frac{a(a+1)}{2} +a\\
&= \frac{b(b+1) - a(a+1) + 2a}{2}\\
&= \frac{b^2-a^2 + b+a}{2}\\
&= \frac{(b-a)(b+a) + b+a}{2}\\
&= \frac{(b-a+1)(a+b)}{2}\\
\end{align*}$$

Comment: The duplicate was found [using Approach$0$](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bi%3Da%7D%5Eb%20i%24&p=1).

Comment: @peterwhy Ok I now see what I was missing thanks to your comment... +1